# Angular Dart Tutorial - Unable to find modules for some sources

Tags: angular-dart

I'm trying to follow the Angular Dart tutorial (https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt1) but got stuck after adding some html that makes use of the ngModel directive.

According to the tutorial in order to make use of the ngModel directive one has to add "angular_forms: ^2.0.0" to the pubspec.yaml, import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart' and add "formDirectives" to the component directives. I did all of that including running "pub get" to get the dependencies but when I run "webdev serve" I get the following error:

```
[SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on test/app_test.dart (cached):
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think I was running into the same issue. As long you are just following the tutorial and don't use testing, you could try to uncomment everything, including all includes, except following method: void main() {} in test/app_test.dart. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same the problem. I don't think it mentions explicityly in the tute but after adding angular_forms dependency to the pubspec.yaml file, you need to pull in this new dependency with:

```
pub get
```

Hope it helps!